Not a cross, not a word (number crossword)
Just a number crossword, but it has no Across clues, only Down clues. Leading 0s are allowed.

Down

A: Cube of the only digit not present in the puzzle
B: Product of four distinct primes
C: Important Well-known physics constant rounded to three digits.

Pretend I said "well-known" instead of "important" for clue C. It might be something you don't need to look up, even if you're not a physicist.

A could be 343 or 512

@TheEmptyStringPhotographer Could it? Read carefully ;)

I just read that leading 0s are allowed, but that only means 027 is an additional possibility for A.

Also, due to clue A, all digits in the crossword have to be unique

Given that there's only one digit that doesn't appear in the grid, there can be no repeats, so it was a quick task to go through all the cubes, and a slightly more tedious task to go through all the three-digit products of 4 distinct primes.
This is the grid I got

 
 0 5 9
 2 4 8
 7 6 1

With the answers obtained from

 A: cube of 3, the only digit not in the grid
 B: product of 2, 3, 7, and 13
 C: One standard gravity in m/s^2, rounded to three digits


Ah, it would have been really useful if that constant had been in the list on the Wiki page I relied upon! The one you mention here should probably have sprung to mind on reflection...

Great minds think alike, but yours was faster or at least read the q earlier. +1.

The final 'crossword' should be filled like this:

 5 6 3
1 9 7
2 0 4

The steps to fill it are actually quite tricky and require some logical case-bashing and trawling of data sources, like so...
Step 1:
We can pick up on a key rule straight away as a consequence of column 1's definition...

 Since there is a solitary digit not present in the puzzle, each cell must be filled with a different digit 0-9, and one of the digits in that range will not be used at all. This means that none of our 3-digit answers can have a repeated digit.

This can be used to narrow down the candidates for A...

 The cubes of the single digits are as follows (with reasons for exclusion if immediately obvious):

 0 cubed = 000 NOPE (repeated 0)
 1 cubed = 001 NOPE (repeated 0)
 2 cubed = 008 NOPE (repeated 0)
 3 cubed = 027 MAYBE
 4 cubed = 064 NOPE (answer cannot include the digit that is its cube root, by definition)
 5 cubed = 125 NOPE (ditto)
 6 cubed = 216 NOPE (ditto)
 7 cubed = 343 NOPE (repeated 0)
 8 cubed = 512 MAYBE
 9 cubed = 729 NOPE (includes digit that is its cube root)

 This means we have two possible candidates for A: 027 (and so '3' is unused) or 512 (and so '8' is unused). Note that whichever of these we use, this number will make use of a '2' digit, so none of our other answers can use a '2'. Furthermore, our other answers cannot use 0 or 7 together with 1 or 5, since that would invalidate both established candidates for A. Keep all of these facts in mind (we'll need them)...

Step 2:
Next, consider B alongside a helpful table showing all the prime factorisations of 3-digit numbers. We are only interested in those that have exactly 4 distinct prime factors. By examining the table, the candidates are thus (with exclusions from the simplest applications of the established logical rules):

 210 (2*3*5*7) NOPE (uses the 2)
 330 (2*3*5*11) NOPE (two digits the same)
 390 (2*3*5*13) MAYBE
 462 (2*3*7*11) NOPE (uses the 2)
 510 (2*3*5*17) NOPE (uses both 1 and 0)
 546 (2*3*7*13) MAYBE
 570 (2*3*5*19) NOPE (uses 0/7 and 5)
 690 (2*3*5*23) MAYBE
 714 (2*3*7*17) NOPE (uses 7 and 1)
 770 (2*5*7*11) NOPE (two digits the same)
 798 (2*3*7*19) MAYBE
 858 (2*3*11*13) NOPE (two digits the same)
 870 (2*3*5*29) MAYBE
 910 (2*5*7*13) NOPE (uses both 1 and 0)
 930 (2*3*5*31) MAYBE
 966 (2*3*7*23) NOPE (two digits the same)

So we've narrowed it down to the following (with more complex exclusions to follow):

 390 (2*3*5*13) – would force A=512 with no 8
 546 (2*3*7*13) – would force A=027 with no 3
 690 (2*3*5*23) – would force A=512 with no 8
 798 (2*3*7*19) – would force A=512 with no 8 - CONTRADICTION, so NOPE
 870 (2*3*5*29) – would force A=512 with no 8 - CONTRADICTION, so NOPE
 930 (2*3*5*31) – would force A=512 with no 8

This leaves us with just 4 candidates - let's see what digits remain in these instances once we take out those we have used:

 390 (2*3*5*13) – would force A=512 with no 8 i.e. ---4-67.--
 546 (2*3*7*13) – would force A=027 with no 3 i.e. 1-.----89-
 690 (2*3*5*23) – would force A=512 with no 8 i.e. --34--7.--
 930 (2*3*5*31) – would force A=512 with no 8 i.e. ---4-67.--

 This means the last column must contain the digits 189, 347, or 467 in some order.

Step 3:
To solve for C, let's consult a list of the main physical constants. Scanning the first 3 digits of all the entries in this list only produces one viable possibility...

 The first radiation constant = 3.74 *10^-16

This fixes our answer for C and thus the others...

 i.e. C must be 3.74, B must be 690 and A must be 512.

Or, to present the result as a grid:

 5 6 3
1 9 7
2 0 4


A note to anyone reading this answer before Bass's - our final answers are entirely different, albeit having followed similar processes. While I like to think mine is still valid as the question is originally worded (re an 'important' physics constant), Bass's choice for C (unfortunately missing from the data source I consulted) is undeniably better known and so you should definitely go and read his answer too.

I would lean towards the gravitational constant as something you "don't" need to look "up", so Bass's answer is a little better to me.

@OscarLanzi "don't" need to look "up", lol. There wasn't even supposed to be a pun there. Nice observation.
